# No errors: But its not indexing faces and not generating the face id's

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable-unpacking

Thank you so much :) Please find the entire code

import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxx', aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',)

collectionId='xxxxxxxxx' #collection name

rek_client=boto3.client('rekognition', aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxx', aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',)

bucket = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' #S3 bucket name

all_objects = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket =bucket )

for content in all_objects['Contents']:

```
collection_name, sep, collection_image =content['Key'].parition('/')

if collection_image:
    label = collection_name
    print('indexing: ',label)

    image = content['Key']
    index_response=rek_client.index_faces(CollectionId=collectionId,
                            Image={'S3Object': 'Bucket':bucket,'Name':image}},
                            ExternalImageId=label,
                            MaxFaces=1,
                            QualityFilter="AUTO", DetectionAttributes=['ALL'])
```

print('FaceId: ',index_response['FaceRecords'][0]['Face']['FaceId'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection_name,collection_image =content['Key'].split('/')
```

requires that `content['Key']` contain *exactly* one forward slash (`/`).

The error indicates that it contains none, so `.split('/')` just returned the equivalent of doing `[content['Key']]` (making a `list` with one element, the entire contents of `content['Key']`). Thus, you only have one value to unpack, but you tried to unpack to two values, and get the error you see.

You either need to filter out the values that don't meet your requirements, or use a system that guarantees you get the expected number of values, e.g. [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
collection_name, sep, collection_image = content['Key'].partition('/')
```

With `str.partition`, if the partition string doesn't occur, then `sep` and `collection_image` will be assigned the empty string, `""`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) But its not indexing faces and not displaying the face id's..Below is my entire code. Please help me

Comment: @user11649630: I think you need to ask a new question. This looks like a completely different problem.

Comment: @user11649630: You really need to ask a new question (you can link to this question for context, but make the new question complete). As you can see, code doesn't really post well in comments.

Comment: I am able to execute the code but output is not displaying. I am working on facial recognition using aws and Raspberrpi. The output should index the faces which are uploaded in the aws s3 bucket...i have posted new post with entire code.I hope you will be getting update of new post...if not please let me know.